# Multipole expansion of two moving charges...Dipole moment is zero, but time derivative should not be?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, dipole-moment

I am reading Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics (2013) on the topic of Cartesian Multipole Radiation. Specially, in equation 20.150 (page 745), he uses the zeroth order approximation (with respect to small source distribution size) to the current density integral:

$$ \int{\vec{J}(r',t)} \space d^3r'= \sum q_i v_i(t) =\frac{d}{dt}\sum q_i r_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{p}(t)$$

where $r$ is the observation vector magnitude, $r'$ is the source vector magnitude and $\vec{p}(t)$ is the dipole moment. This all makes sense for me so far until I think of a simple thought experiment:

If we have two equal charges, q, traveling in the x-y plane with velocities parallel to each other and the x-axis, and separated by a distance, $\pm d$, along the y-axis, respectively.

[image]

Now, my confusion comes for the two different values in the above equations:

$$ \sum q_i v_i(t) = e\vec{v} + e\vec{v} = 2e\vec{v}$$

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\sum q_i r_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \left( {ed + e(-d)} \right) =  \frac{d}{dt} \left( {0} \right) = 0$$

Can anyone help clear my confusion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in  a dipole radiator the charges oscillate *along* (and not perpendicular to) their connecting line

Comment: Yes, I know that but this is a different orientation. I guess I am just more confused about the math of the summation; if you sum the dipole moment you get zero, but if you sum the velocities you get something not zero.